# Probability of selecting 1 white ball given $t$ removed balls

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, expected-value

I have a sack of $b$ balls, $w$ of which are white. I uniformly and randomly throw exactly $t$ $(0 \leq t < b)$ of the balls away. I then randomly select one of the remaining $b-t$ balls.

What is the probability that I have selected a white ball?

Based off the information I am given, since there is an equal chance of $b$, $t$, $w$ being any number, I have a sense that the answer is $\frac{w}{b}$, but I am lacking the intuition behind this answer. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you instead just pick a ball, the answer is $w/b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct, as your method is equivalent to pick a single ball from the whole sack.  If you drew all the balls in order, each (such as the $t+1$th ball) would have probability $\frac{w}{b}$ of being white, even though these events would not be independent

The complicated calculation would be to consider the possibility that $v$ of the first $t$ were white and $t-v$ were black.  The probability of this would be $\dfrac{{w \choose v}{b-w \choose t-v}}{b \choose t}$.  The conditional probability that the $t+1$th ball would then be white would be $\frac{w-v}{b-t}$.  So the overall probability that the $t+1$th ball is white is $$\sum_v\frac{{w \choose v}{b-w \choose t-v}}{b \choose t} \frac{w-v}{b-t}$$ and this can be rewritten as $$=\sum_v\frac{w{w-1 \choose v}{b-w \choose t-v}}{b{b-1 \choose t}}=\frac{w}{b}\sum_v\frac{{w-1 \choose v}{b-w \choose t-v}}{{b-1 \choose t}} = \frac{w}{b} $$

Comment: Ah thank you! This makes a lot of sense. Did you use Probability Mass Function for the summation?

Comment: @user11235813 - it uses the probability mass function of the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution)