# Probability of removing at least 1 white ball given randomly selected remaining ball is white

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, expected-value

Followup to this question: [Probability of selecting 1 white ball given $t$ removed balls](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2975784/probability-of-selecting-1-white-ball-given-t-removed-balls)

Let there be an urn of $b$ balls, $w$ of which are white. Uniformly and randomly throw away exactly $t,(0≤t<b)$ balls. Then randomly select one of the remaining $b−t$ balls.

Given that the randomly selected ball is white, what is the probability that at least one of the thrown away balls is white?

I would appreciate some feedback on my work as I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. So if we let $A$ be the event that that the randomly selected ball is white and $B$ be the event that at least one of the thrown away balls is white. Then we want to find $P(B|A) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}$

Since $A, B$ aren't necessarily independent events, then we must solve $P(A \cap B) = P(B)*P(A|B)$.

I know that $P(B) = 1 - \frac{{b-w \choose t}}{b \choose t}$ from limiting the range of PMF of the problem to $[1,c]$ instead of $[0,c]$.

I also know that $P(A) = \frac{w}{b}$.

But when I solve for $P(A|B)$ using PMF and solution presented in the link above, I just get $P(A)*P(B)$ which doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Please advise. Thank you.
Also feedback on my solution would be nice too

Edit: Typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a third answer:

- $P(A)$ is the probability that the $t+1$th randomly selected ball is white
- $P(B)$ is the probability that at least one of the $t$ thrown away balls are white
- $P(B^c)=1-P(B)$ is the probability that none of the $t$ thrown away balls are white

Then I would have thought

- $P(A)=\dfrac{w}{b}$
- $P(B^c) = \dfrac{{b-w \choose t}}{b \choose t}$
- $P(A \mid B^c) = \dfrac{w}{b-t}$
- $P(A \cap B^c) = \dfrac{w}{b-t}\dfrac{{b-w \choose t}}{b \choose t}$
- $P(B^c \mid A) = \dfrac{b}{b-t}\dfrac{{b-w \choose t}}{b \choose t}=\dfrac{{b-w \choose t}}{b-1 \choose t}$
- $P(B \mid A) = 1 - \dfrac{{b-w \choose t}}{b-1 \choose t}$

As an illustration of the differences, consider $w=2,b=4,t=2$: my expression gives an answer of $\frac23$ while molloculle's answer gives $\frac{5}{12}$ and  Graham Kemp's gives $\frac12$.  I think that if the third ball is white, there is a $\frac23$ probability the other white ball was one of the first two thrown away and a $\frac13$ probability the other white ball was the remaining fourth ball.  Looking at it another way in this example, of the $4!=24$ ways of ordering the four balls, $12$ have the third ball white and $8$ of those $12$ have at least one of the first two balls white, with $\frac{8}{12}=\frac23$

Comment: Ohh, this makes a lot more sense. This seems more correct. I realized that my answer does not work when $n = c$ or when $c = 0$ either. Thank you for this answer.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you so much for explaining!

Answer (score 0):

You have a heap of $b$ balls, of which $w$ are white. You are randomly arranging that into three heaps of $t$ discarded, $1$ selected, and $b-t-1$ remaining balls; with $t$ uniformly distributed over $\{0..b-1\}$.   You seek the probability for not-none of the discarded balls are white given that the selected ball is.

For a particular $t$, there are $\binom{b-t}{w}$ ways that none of the white balls are among the discards.   There are $\binom b w$ ways to arrange the balls in total.   Now $t$ varies between $0$ to $b-w$ (as any further and it is impossible to not-discard some white balls), with each value occuring with probability of $1/b$.

Hence $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(B)&=1-\dfrac 1b\sum\limits_{t=0}^{b-w}\dfrac{\dbinom{b-t}w}{\dbinom bw}\\[1ex]&~\vdots\tag{why?}\\[1ex] &=1-\dfrac 1b\cdot\dfrac{(b+1)}{(w+1)}\\[1ex] &=\dfrac{bw-1}{bw+b}\end{align}$$

---

There are $\binom{b-t-1}{w-1}\binom 11$ ways none of the white balls are among the discards *and* the selected ball is white.   There are $\binom{b-1}{w-1}\binom 11$ ways the selected ball may be white, in total.   Also $t$ behaves as before.

$$\mathsf P(B\mid A)=1-\dfrac 1b\cdot\dfrac{(b-1)+1}{(w-1)+1)}=\dfrac{w-1}w$$

Comment: Thank you for explaining, but I am still a little confused. Shouldn't there be ${b \choose t}$ total ways of arranging the balls?

Comment: No. @jello $~$ We are counting ways to select *places* for the white balls.  There are $b$ places among which we may put the $w$ white balls in total.

Comment: Oh I see. Did you use PMF or expected value for where your ellipsis are? Also I am kind of lost as to how you got to P(B|A) since you have P(A and B) and P(A) below but used P(B) in your answer. Finally, w-1/w seems like a very high probability. how can this be so?

Comment: $\mathsf P(B\mid A) =1-\dfrac 1b \sum\limits_{t=0}^{b-w}\dfrac{\dbinom{b-1-t}{w-1}}{\dbinom{b-1}{w-1}}$

Comment: Wait is your final answer missing a factor of $P(B)$?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct answer for this should be:
$$\frac{n-c-p}{n-p}*(1 - \frac{{b-w \choose t}}{{b \choose t}})*\frac{n}{c}$$
I did this a slightly different method than how Mr. Kemp did it.

Let $P(A)$ represent the probability that our randomly selected ball is white

Let $P(B)$ represent the probability that at least one of the thrown away balls are white

Since we know that 
$$P ( B | A ) = \frac { P ( A \cap B ) } { P ( A ) }$$
And $A, B$ are independent events, so we must substitute $P ( A \cap B ) = P ( B ) * P ( A | B )$, we can find each of these.

$P(A) = \frac{w}{b}$ from the linked problem.

$P(B) = 1 - \frac{{b-w \choose t}}{{b \choose t}}$

I found this by limiting the following sum:
$$\sum _ { v } \frac { \left( \begin{array} { c } { w } \\ { v } \end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array} { l } { b - w } \\ { t - v } \end{array} \right) } { \left( \begin{array} { l } { b } \\ { t } \end{array} \right) }$$
from $v = [1, n]$ instead of $[0,c]$, that is, I subtracted $v = 0$ from the sum.

$P(A|B) = \frac{n - c - p}{n - p}$ We can find this by complementary counting. If we instead find the probability of $A$ given $\overline{B}$, that is the event that we throw away no white balls, then that probability is $\frac{c}{n-p}$. We then take $1 - \frac{c}{n-p}$.

Now substitute everything back into the conditional probability equation and we get that

$$\frac{n-c-p}{n-p}*(1 - \frac{{b-w \choose t}}{{b \choose t}})*\frac{n}{c}$$